# Block cipher birthday bound and a KDF workaround

Tags: block-cipher, key-derivation, birthday-attack

Can the birthday bound arising from a block cipher’s block size be worked around by deriving different keys from the master key with a KBKDF using a tweak?

For example consider the following scheme, which assumes

- **K** is a 256-bit key
- **tweak** is an integer we can increment before 2^64 blocks have been encrypted with the current generation

and then encrypts as follows:

- **IV** = random 256 bits
- **EffectiveKey** = KDF(K, context=tweak)
- ciphertext = KeyGeneration || IV || AES-CBC(IV, EffectiveKey, plain)

Would this scheme be secure for encrypting more than 2^64 blocks?

Asked in order to learn more about the birthday bound.

EDIT - this has similarities to the construction used in the [Better Bounds for Block Cipher Modes of Operation via
Nonce-Based Key Derivation](https://acmccs.github.io/papers/p1019-gueronA.pdf) paper ([great talk too](https://youtu.be/8Db9Q8Sg21Q?t=423) by [Yehuda Lindell](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/25354/yehuda-lindell)), which also introduces AES-GCM-SIV.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you assume blocklength is $128$ bits. I believe the following is correct.

One might try rainbow table TMTO attacks, assuming known plaintext, and succeed with time and memory complexity somewhat better than
$$
O(2^{(2/3)k})
$$
where $k$ is the effective keylenth,
against such a scheme but it would be secure beyond the birthday bound.

Comment: Got a link describing the TMTO attacks? Sounds really interesting. How does using the KDF figure into it? I'm assuming this isn't a valid attack when rotating to newly generated keys instead of ones generated with a KDF.